# Weblogic 12c Timer issue

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

i have a EJB Module that use EJB3.1 Timer Annotation for Scheduling but on some cases when my method get Exception after 2 or 3 timer attempts , timer kill and not call again.
i think about solution for increase timer attempt on weblogic 12c but can't find anything.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13719/implementing.htm#autoId26), it looks like WebLogic has its own implementation of the TimerService interface, which allows you to set the maximum number of retries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might fix your issue:

Bug 19689036 : NON-PERSISTENT CALENDAR-BASED TIMER IS CANCELED IF CALLBACK METHOD THROWS SYSTEM